# Form like table

Tags: html, css

I want to create a table where each td is a form field. What is the best way of approaching that? Should I create a regular table and apply css styles on the form fields to resemble the size of the td fields? Hmmm... what do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

You can place tags inside of a form easily, so I would recommend nesting a table in the form:

```
<form>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    <td>Age: <input type="text" name="age" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Which would give you a one row, two column table with a labeled text box in each column.  Be careful about nesting your HTML tags, this could get confusing fast if you made a large table/form.

Answer (score 1):

People seem to be forgetting about `display: table`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell!`

Here's a [demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVqmU/1/).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [contenteditable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```
<html>
    <table>
         <tr>
              <td>
                  <div contenteditable="true"></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
</html
```